# What kilogram is doing in volt unit definition?

Tags: units

My question is inspired by this: [Why do farads multiplied by ohms produce a result that has a unit of seconds?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138296/why-is-the-time-constantrc-measured-in-seconds)

I want to ask what kilogram is doing in this equation:

$$\mathrm{V = \frac{kg \cdot m^2}{A \cdot s^3}}$$

Comment: Unit cancellation is weird: https://what-if.xkcd.com/11/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Voltage is used to measure the potential difference between one point and a reference point. The reference point when its ground voltage becomes a node or a point voltage. Now potential is defined as the "Work done in bringing a point charge from infinity to the given location". The Work done is Force multiplied by displacement and The force involves mass of the particle (unit +ve charge), which in SI units is in kg.

Comment: This explains **why**, whereas the accepted answer is just a bunch of formulae that only really make sense if you already understand why.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree too. This is a much better explanation than the raw formulas. I have updated my vote.

Answer (score 33):

It's part of the Force. Well, just force actually. Which is mass times acceleration.

\$\mathrm{V=\dfrac{J}{C}}\$

\$\mathrm{J = N\cdot m}\$

\$\mathrm{N = \dfrac{kg\cdot m}{s^2}}\$

\$\mathrm{C = A\cdot s}\$

Comment: "Use the Force, Kamil!"

Answer (score 12):

Let \$P\$ be power in watts, \$I\$ be current in amps, \$W\$ be work in Joules,

\$A\$ Acceleration in meters per \$\text{second}^2\$ \$D\$ distance in meters, \$M\$ Mass in kg.

\$T\$ Time in seconds, \$F\$ Force in newtons and \$V\$ voltage in volts.

We know \$ P = V \cdot I\$ so \$V = \dfrac{P}{I}\$.

Basic physics should tell you Power is Work divided by time \$P = \dfrac{W}{T}\$.

Work is Force times distance \$W = F \cdot D\$

Force is mass times Acceleration \$F = M \cdot A\$.

Putting all this together we see.

\$ V = \dfrac{P}{I} = \dfrac{W}{I \cdot T} = \dfrac{F \cdot D}{I \cdot T} = \dfrac{M \cdot A \cdot D}{I \cdot T} = \dfrac{M \cdot D \cdot D}{I \cdot T \cdot T^2} = \dfrac{M \cdot D^2}{I \cdot T^3}\$

Using standard SI units the volt is therefore \$\dfrac{\mathrm{kg} \cdot \mathrm{m}^2}{\mathrm{A} \cdot \mathrm{s}^3}\$

Answer (score 8):

Imagine a uniform electric field, pointing to the right.  Consider two points A,B, where B is one meter to the right of A.  Suppose the difference in potential between A and B is one volt.

At point A, put an object with a mass of **one kilogram** which has a positive charge of one coulomb (one amp-second).  The object will be pushed towards B by the electric field.  As it moves towards B, it will experience a force sufficient to accelerate it at a rate of one meter per second per second.

In other words, one volt is the potential difference which, over a distance of one meter, will cause an object with charge one coulomb and mass one kilogram to accelerate at a rate of one meter per second per second.

If the object's mass were two kilograms, it would only accelerate at one-half meter per second per second.

Answer (score 5):

As other have mentioned, voltage is a measure of energy per unit charge. But in the physics of E&M fields, voltage is also used to calculate the electric field. Specifically: $$-E = \nabla V$$

In English, this means that the gradient of the voltage gives the electric field. (If you don't know vector calculus, think of it as the vector equivalent of E = dV/dx.) The units of the electric field are Newtons/Coulomb (force / charge), and mass is part of the definition of force. That's why the kilogram is there -- the energy in an electric circuit is transferred through a **force** field! You can see this more clearly if you separate out the units:
$$Physics: Voltage = Efield \cdot distance \space$$
$$Units: V = \frac{N}{C} \cdot m$$
$$V = N \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot m$$
$$V = \frac{kg \cdot m}{s^2} \cdot \frac{1}{A \cdot s} \cdot m$$
$$V = \frac{kg \cdot m^2}{A \cdot s^3}$$

Answer (score 4):

As an interesting side light.  It may soon be that the kilogram is defined in terms of the volt.  (Well more than just the volt.) See the [watt balance.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt_balance)

Comment: "Any laboratory which had invested the (very considerable) time and money in a working watt balance would be able to measure masses to the same accuracy as they currently measure the Planck constant." **Infinite awesomeness achieved.**

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I read a nice physics today article about it few months ago, still here.http://www.nymanz.org/Nonlinear/documents/2014-Newell-PhysicsToday-AmorefundamentalInternationalSystemofUnits.pdf

Comment: although I find this an interesting find and a valuable comment, it doesn't even try to answer the question asked... George, please try to answer *what kg is doing in V definition*, otherwise this answer would be eligible to be flagged as "not an answer".

Comment: @vaxquis, flag away :^) I thought everyone else answered the question.  I guess if you read between the lines, the implication is that there are a limited number of fundamental constants.  And a force can be mass * acceleration (little g) or B x I * L (a current in a B field for some length.)

Comment: little `g` is actually the earth's gravitational constant, not acceleration. Acceleration is `a`.